# How to cast a date column value in JSLink javascript, and how to increase this date variable?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, jslink

I am using sharepoint 2013 online. I have created a custom list. On this list I have used JSLink to show an icon in a column. I would like to do some logic to show a red or a green icon. I have now in js 2 dates. The date from my column from the current item and the date of today. I would like to do the following check:

```
var contractEndDate = ctx.CurrentItem.Contract_x0020_einddatum;

    var today = new Date();


    if((contractEndDate + 10 days) > today)
    {
        return "<img src='https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/Sales/SiteAssets/green.png'/>";
    }
    else
    {
        return "<img src='https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/Sales/SiteAssets/red.png'/>";
    }
```

How can I cast the var contractEndDate to a date? And how can I increase it with 10 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the format of contractEndDate is in this case but try:

```
var contractEndDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Contract_x0020_einddatum);
var compareDate = contractEndDate.getDate() + 10
var today = new Date();

if(compareDate > today)
{
    return "<img src='https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/Sales/SiteAssets/green.png'/>";
}
else
{
    return "<img src='https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/teams/Sales/SiteAssets/red.png'/>";
}
```

There is a risk that `new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Contract_x0020_einddatum)` will throw an error... in which case you need to use a supporting method like this one:

```
function convertSPDate(d) {
/*
*   A function to convert a standard SharePoint
*   date/time field (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) to a
*   javascript Date() object
*
*   Author: Ben Tedder (www.bentedder.com)
*/
    // split apart the date and time
    var xDate = d.split(" ")[0];
    var xTime = d.split(" ")[1];

    // split apart the hour, minute, & second
    var xTimeParts = xTime.split(":");
    var xHour = xTimeParts[0];
    var xMin = xTimeParts[1];
    var xSec = xTimeParts[2];

    // split apart the year, month, & day
    var xDateParts = xDate.split("-");
    var xYear = xDateParts[0];
    var xMonth = xDateParts[1];
    var xDay = xDateParts[2];

    var dDate = new Date(xYear, xMonth - 1, xDay, xHour, xMin, xSec);
    return dDate;
}
```

found [here](http://www.bentedder.com/convert-a-sharepoint-datetime-field-to-a-javascript-date-object/) but slightly modified (since month is zerobased in javascript Date())

Comment: I have try first to return the variable contractEndDate to check if it is filled and give me this error:

Invalid Date

I think it is not possible to cast this sharepoint value to date. I see some examples on internet where they are split the string in day, month and year. This is realy ugly. I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: That might be the way you need to go

Comment: Thanks, we are almost there. Why contractEndDate.getDate() returns 4 ? 4 is the day of the date object.

Comment: Yepp, Date == dayOfMonth

Comment: Thanks it works! only one fix: var dDate = new Date(xYear, xMonth - 1, xDay, xHour, xMin, xSec);

Comment: Great to hear that! Ah yes, JS month is zerobased :P

Comment: Hello, I run into a similar problem so I thought to ask here first before asking a new question. 
@KHA, which locale were you using? was the SP date&time column date only? I'm currently getting "invalid date"
When I call the function above to cast the date in a valid Format (I call it like this: var eta1 = convertSPDate(ctx.CurrentItem.ETA_x0020_1); ) and try to return eta1 just to test it, the SP item disappears
Any insights, Details might help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, I am looking to do something very similar...but I have getting an error with the function. TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'split'TypeError: Do i need to add.sp.js?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `contractEndDate` is a [DateTime field type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielddatetime.aspx):

```
var today = new Date();
var contractExpiredDate = new Date(contractEndDate); // create Date object from date string
contractExpiredDate.setDate(contractEndDate.getDate() + 10);

if (contractExpiredDate > today) {
   //The remaining code is committed for clarity 
}
```

Comment: this is not working: var contractExpiredDate = new Date(contractEndDate);

Comment: hmm.. i've tested it and it works for me, could you please share some details about error..